# SQL Questionaire Database Design (EAV Model) Issue

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

Im building a friendship site where I try and match users who share similar interests.

- I have 25 questions with defined answers(drop down answers) that the user must fill out.
- Im using an **entity–attribute–value model** to store the users id the question id the answered id the  user selects.
- I then use the count function to see which users have the most matches to my profile.

**Current Table Structure**

1. Question Table
2. Answer Table
3. Question_Answer_User Table

The problem im running into is I have two question and im not sure where the best place to store them is.

1. The question is what is your country?
2. The question is what is your State?

Im not sure if I should store them with the other 25 questions or if i should store them in a three separate tables as seen below.

1. country table
2. state table
3. user_country_state Table

There are going to be alot of answer entries for these 2 questions. For example there are 25 countries the user can answer and a total of 900 states / provinces the user can answer from.

I want to be able to consider the users location as similarity to count but im not sure what the best approach to incorporate this is?

Comment: I would add an "importance" option to the questions to weigh them when making the matches. If distance is important, maybe you can track the user locations at the user level, not as a question, and have a question about the max distance instead. Then use something like "The Google Distance Matrix API" to calculate the distances. Of course you would need to show the locations using Google Maps if you go this route, but there might be other services out there can do something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the selected country and state should live in the user table, along with the other necessary user information such as name and email address.  I don't think it belongs in the Answers table, but it would work there.

For the list of options for the user to select from when setting up his account, storing them in your pre-defined Q and A tables are as good a place as any.  It depends, I guess, on how your data and functionality is broken apart so that you aren't crossing responsibility boundaries for the Q&A table storing survey-type answers as well as user-setup answers.

Comment: I have a user table, thats what im trying to figure out if, i should put the country and state in the user table as a  varchar or if i should put it in the question and answer table.

Comment: I like you answer Cindy, but do you think i might take a hit on performance when i search for users in certain states, cause it will be searching varchar  variables instead of an int datatype.

Comment: I was assuming you would store them as identity keys, not as varchars.  But that is getting into an entirely new issue of performance vs ease of programming. If your database isn't too big, you could get away with storing them as var chars but I always prefer to use numeric keys for something like that.  Are you storing all your regular answers as their full values or as their key values?

Comment: regular answers are stored as keys, thats why i wasnt sure were to put this. If i store the country as a key in my user table I would need to create a country table and a state table (which is fine) but i wasnt sure which is the best approach. Approach 1 : create a key for country and state in the user table, Approach 2 : dont add anything to the user table and add the country and state to the question answer table as keys. Thinking in terms of best preformance what would you do?

Comment: I prefer approach 1 overall.  I thought you were talking about approach 3, though: add the country and state to the question and answer table as keys and store those keys in the user table.

Comment: Thanks Cindy, I think I willl go with approach 1.